# Best practise: How many zen discovery nodes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch cluster on AWS consisting of 11 nodes. The nodes are using Zen unicast Discovery (multicast is disabled). This requires a list of `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` to be defined. How many nodes is best practises to have in the list? 11? 3 stable nodes? Also, what are the implications of having different nodes listed on different nodes? Could that lead to a split brain scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have dedicated master nodes, the easiest would be to list the master nodes in the `unicast.hosts` lists. Otherwise, is not required to list all 11 nodes, but would be preferable to.

The role of the `unicast.hosts` list is to help a node that just joined the cluster to *learn* about the structure of the cluster from the nodes listed in that list. So, it's best to provide nodes there that definitely will be available. It's ok to provide just one node there, but are you sure that node will always be up and available?

If you don't have dedicated master nodes, just list all the nodes in there. In this way, you are sure the list is good and, also, you can use almost the same configuration file for all the nodes (except the node name setting).

Regarding split brain, all you need to do is [setting up the `minimum_master_nodes`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html#master-election).

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! Must all nodes have an identical `unicast.hosts` list?

Comment: No, that's not required. But when you have 11 configuration files to manage, if you want to change something in them you need to pay attention to the particularities of each node. And it can prove difficult to maintain. That's why I mentioned putting there all the 11 nodes and have the same setting in all the config files.

Comment: Interesting. I just experienced a split brain and am trying to figure out why. The hosts had different `unicast.hosts`...

Comment: Do you have `minimum_master_nodes` set to the quorum of master-eligible nodes?

Comment: No. But wouldn't that simply have made half of my cluster fail on write? That is, I would still have split-brain.

Comment: No :-). That setting is a must. You need to put that setting in all the master-eligible nodes `elasticsearch.yml` file and restart the nodes (or the whole cluster if you need to put that on all your nodes).

Comment: Cool! :-) Will put it in my cluster conf immediately. Thanks!